# Javascript / ES6 parse value from arrays of objects

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I want to write a generic parser which takes a value, and type and returns label of given value instead.

Currently, this is my code:

```
import a from "../constants/a"
import b from "../constants/b"
import c from "../constants/c"

const find = (value, fromArray) => fromArray.find((term) => term.value === value);
const getLabel = (of, fromArray) => {
    const value = find(of, fromArray);
    return (value && value.label) || 'No info';
};


export default (value, type) => {
    switch (type) {
        case 'paymentMethod':
            return getLabel(value, paymentMethods);
        case 'paymentTerm':
            return getLabel(value, paymentTerms);
        case 'dateType':
            return getLabel(value, dateTypes);
        default:
            return 'No info';
    }
}
```

What would be more ES6, faster and concise way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Granularity

All code can be said to have a level of granularity. This is a measure of how many functions it contains. Low granularity has fewer larger functions that has benefits of faster run-times at the expense of readability, while high granularity has many smaller functions, trading off performance for more readable and maintainable code.

Just how granular to make some code is something that comes from experience as there are no hard and fast rules to go by. However there is a general rule of thumb that increasing granularity should always reduce code complexity and source code size.

#### Too granular

Your code is too granular,

- It is bloated with the source required only to define functions, call and pass arguments.
- It adds un-needed complexity with arguments transforming the abstraction implied by naming from one `value` to another `of` and then back again to `value`.
- It has forced you to repeat code.
- It contains a function that is only an alias for existing functions `find` is an alias for `Array.find` and provides no additional processing.

The function `getLabel` processes  the result of `find` returning `"No info"` for undefined results. But this is repeated in the calling function.

#### Reducing granularity to improve code

Reducing granularity will not always improve code, well I should say very seldom and only in the case where the code is already too granulated.

Your module can be done in a single function

```
export default (value, type) => {
    var array, result;
    switch (type) {
        case 'paymentMethod':
            array = paymentMethods;
            break;
        case 'paymentTerm':
            array = paymentTerms;
            break;
        case 'dateType':
            array = dateTypes;
    }
    if (array) { result = array.find(item => item.value === value) }
    return result && result.label || "No info"
}
```

Or as there are only a few cases in the `switch` use `if` `else`

```
export default (value, type) => {
    var array, result;
    if(type === "paymentMethod") { array = paymentMethods }
    else if(type === "paymentTerm") { array = paymentTerms }
    else if(type === "dateType") { array = dateTypes }

    if (array) { result = array.find(item => item.value === value) }
    return result && result.label || "No info"
}
```

This can be even further reduced by using `type` to index the array via bracket notation, replacing the unwieldy `switch` or `if` `else` statements

```
const types = {paymentMethods, paymentTerms, dateTypes};
export default (value, type) => {
    var result;    
    const name = type + "s";
    if (types[name]) { result = types[name].find(item => item.value === value) }
    return result && result.label || "No info";
}
```

Or if the names are not always pluralized with an s.

```
const types = {paymentMethod:paymentMethods, paymentTerm:paymentTerms, dateType:dateTypes};
export default (value, type) => {
    var result;    
    if (types[type]) { result = types[type].find(item => item.value === value) }
    return result && result.label || "No info";
}
```

#### Your questions

> What would be more ES6, faster and concise way to achieve this?

- More ES6? Not really, the  ES6 - eness of the code has not changed.
- Faster? Yes there is less code to execute and few function states to create, push, and pop from the call stack.
- Concise? Yes in my view it is much more concise. From 17 lines and three functions to 6 lines, one function, and no repeated code.

Comment: In your last iteration - anything with the type `paymentTerm` won't work as the variable is `paymentTerms`

Comment: @Gerrit0 Oh dear I missed that will fix now.

Comment: @Blindman67 thanks for explanation, code also looks great!